# Angular material table drag/drop do not allow drop in the first column

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I have a dynamic material table with the first column with options to view details, edit etc. So I only want the drop to be allowed after the first column. How I can attain this or  use the cdkDragBoundary with in mat table th

```html
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" 
         cdkDropList
         cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; let i=index" [sticky]="isFirstColumn(column)">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef cdkDrag>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!isFirstColumn(column)">
          <div style="float: right">
            <button type="button"
                    class="drag-handle sm-icon-button"
                    [disabled]="isEditDisabled"
                    mat-icon-button cdkDragHandle>
              <mat-icon>drag_handle</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          {{ column}}
        </ng-container>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="w-100 col-left">
        <ng-container *ngIf="isFirstColumn(column)">
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>
              list
            </mat-icon>

          </button>
            <button mat-icon-button
                    [disabled]="isEditDisabled"
                    (click)="onEdit(element)">
              <mat-icon>
                edit
              </mat-icon>

            </button>
          </ng-container>
          <span>{{element[column]}}</span>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!isFirstColumn(column)">
          <ng-container *ngIf="editing.Id && element.Id === editing.Id">
            <input id="{{column}}{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="element[column]" size="10" />
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="!editing.Id || element.Id !== editing.Id">
            {{element[column]}}
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem but managed to solve it by the following code.
Users still can drag and drop but after drop, we are preventing the original array from changing.

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
 if(event.currentIndex == 0) {
   return;
 }
 moveItemInArray(this.dataSource, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```